# when ever i request for testnet goerli or sepolia i receive the testnet some random address it been received from me

Tags: metamask, address.transfer

this address is receiving all my testnet eth 0x000ED96F3C5636BBB1A4fa59B96C2CCD042e5000
without my permission and approve
[image]

has you can see the second i receive the eth its been send to that address i a second
what should i do

Comment: Transfer out all your tokens on mainnet using a different computer. That is the first thing you should do.

Comment: Your private key is compromised.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like, you are attacking by the bot. The bot got your private key and now, it is sending all funds in your wallet to the bot's wallet. So the bot is stealing your money in front of you now.
One way to prevent this is to remove the wallet and not using it ever again.

Comment: like in the mainnet i have money it only happening to my testnets can you please help me

Comment: The only reason the transaction is happening automatically is that the private key is already stolen.
I think the stealer is testing his logic with testnet. So if you fund more money on mainnet, he will also send all the ether to his wallet.0x000ED96F3C5636BBB1A4fa59B96C2CCD042e5000.
One more thing to tell you. I think he is now filtering all of your transactions. So if you send eth to other wallet, his transaction will happen first. Which means you can not send any eth to the other wallet without special technology.
I can help you. But this comment has limit so I can not write here.

Comment: if i create a new wallet in same metamask app then also the bot get all my fund?

Comment: I am not sure if only your wallet private key is stolen or your seed phrase is. I think you should create wallet on other browser for safety. And also I think the bot is filtering your transactions now. So if you send fund to the other wallet, the bot will make transaction faster than you and will get fund. Which means you can not get fund back using normal technology. But don't worry. I know how to prevent this. Please leave me your tg.

Comment: So, you solved your problem?